# i'm trying to add my user to ttyACM0, and it says not found. I accessed it about 30 minutes ago

Tags: linux, arduino, serial-port, tty

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rovAK.png)

I'm new to linux so excuse my lack of terminology. I'm having issues with selecting a com port from arduino IDE. I followed the arduino website installation and tried to access ttyACM0 because that's what the tools>port originally had. I tried giving my user access to the port using the **sudo usermod -a -G dialout**  and then restarted my computer. When I opened up the IDE the "port" selection was greyed out and I cannot select anything. Tried bouncing the cable around to different ports and same result. Did I somehow remove my users permissions for the com ports, and how might I fix this?

Comment: just an update to the situation, as it turns out the board itself was bricked. I could use another Arduino as a programmer to fix that separate issue but both happened at the same time so im not sure how their related but i dont think its coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue some days ago. Somebody else might find useful executing this command:

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

before and after connecting your microcontroller by USB.

Check [the new entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmVYH.png) that may appear.

When you get that entry (Arduino ide may show it in tools-port), proceed with these:

```
ls -l {your port}
```

for example /dev/ttyUSB0
That should diplay something like this:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 0 ene 21 02:35 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The only part that matters is the one that shows **uucp**, the group.

Bearing that in mind, continue with:

```
sudo usermod -a -G {the previously displayed group} {your user}
```

Finally, log out and log in again to make this change effective

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with /dev/ttyACM*. I was using a VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 20 to operate a robotic manipulator and after performing some commands to install packages and updates, the /dev/ttyACM* ports were no longer there. Even after trying to update udev rules, adding user to groups, etc... The `lsusb` and `dmesg` commands didn't show anything related to ttyACM* too but the system was capable of seeing the device under `/dev/bus/usb/...`.

The problem I found was related to the cdc_acm module in /lib/modules. Apparently, new /lib/modules folders are created when there are updates and the older ones are kept.

The solution I found was to run `sudo apt --purge autoremove`. The "purge" argument made the difference for me. This command cleans the older /lib/modules files and after rebooting my system was capable of finding the /dev/ttyACM* ports whenever connected. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

The /dev/ttyACM0 port does not show up in the /dev directory when the device is in File Transfer mode.  Try unplugging/plugging the usb connector, without pushing the BOOT_SEL button.